# Get transactions whose latest status is successful in laravel?

Tags: mysql, laravel, lumen

I have two table.

this is transaction table:

```
        $table->ulid();
        $table->string('payee_user_id', 36);
        $table->string('type', 36);
        $table->string('terminal_id', 36);
        $table->string('terminal_no', 36);
        $table->string('terminal_type', 36);
        $table->string('acceptor_id', 36);
        $table->string('terminal_psp', 36);
        $table->string('terminal_provider', 36);
        $table->decimal('amount_settle', 15, 2);
        $table->decimal('amount_wage', 15, 2);
        $table->string('account_id', 36)->nullable();;
        $table->string('account_bank_id', 36)->nullable();;
        $table->string('account_deposit', 26)->nullable();
        $table->string('account_iban', 26)->nullable();
        $table->string('wallet_id', 36)->nullable();
        $table->timestamp('paid_at', 6);
```

this is status table:

```
        $table->ulid();
        $table->string('transaction_id');
        $table->string('status', 36);
        $table->string('description', 36)->nullable();

        $table->foreign('transaction_id')
            ->on('transactions')->references('id');

        $table->timestamp('created_at', 6)->useCurrent()->index();
```

any transactions has many statuses.I need to get transactions whose latest status is successful.performance is very important. I do not want eloquent.

Answer (score 0):

You are referencing id but your schema shows you are using ulid. If it's id you are using you can change ulid to id below.

```php
    DB::table('transactions')->selectRaw('transactions.ulid as id, transactions.bank_id as bank_id')
        ->leftJoin('statuses', 'transactions.ulid', '=', 'statuses.transaction_id')
        ->where('statues.status', 'successful')
        ->get();
```

Comment: you are checking status is accept. bu i need to check last status. only last status